# "npm/pnpm run dev" doesn't display anything

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, pnpm, npm-run

I'm on windows 11 and I'm working in a nextjs project . After initializing my project using "npx create-next-app@latest", I executed the command "npm run dev" but it display anything even though the initialisation went well .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUGzm.png) problem to solve

---

(from comment)

I have tried many solutions:

- First by deleting node_modules and package_lock.json file before executing npm i cmd but without success.
- After that, I changed npm and use pnpm cmd, initialisation went well but running the project still display anything.
- I also verified the ignore-scripts key configuration and its value is false.

Comment: You need to run `npm install`

Comment: I have tried many solutions: first by deleting node_modules and package_lock.json file before executing npm i cmd but without success. After that, I changed npm and use pnpm cmd, initialisation went well but running the project still display anything.

I also verified the ignore-scripts key configuration and its value is false 

Thanks in advance !

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: please always add such details to your question instead of comments @Cisco_dev_sn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error, it may be worth to just insert your http://localhost:3000 or whatever serveraddress you use into your browser. After the browser shows the website, more information appears in the terminal